# page templates rendered with diazo don't load internationalization strings

Tags: internationalization, plone, diazo, linguaplone

I've developed a nice theme for Plone with Diazo, but I'm still unable to fix a translation problem that I have for those rules where I use a method="document" attribute in order to get contents from two different .pt file.
Here is an example:

```xml
<replace css:theme="#sidebar1"
         css:content="#sidebar1"
         href="/menu"
         method="document"
         if-path="myhome"/>
```

It means the following: when I browse my .pt named myhome, I want to replace the sidebar1 div with contents defined into another page template named menu.pt. And this works fine; the problem is that both the page include some tal 'i18n:translate' instructions and, when I switch language, the translation is correctly loaded for myhome.pt, while it stays in the starting language for the menu.pt file; if I refresh the page or click again on the language selector, then all the translation strings are correctly loaded for the target language. 
I can't explain this strange behavior, did anyone fix a similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've released plone.subrequest 1.6.3 which now copies over `other` request variables such as `LANGUAGE_TOOL` and `LANGUAGE`. Try updating your buildout with this version of plone.subrequest and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @mede: If you find an answer helpful, you can mark it as 'accepted'; it'll give both you and the answerer some reputation points and guides future visitors to the best answer too. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)